# Using WhenAny With Dynamic Sized List

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Does anyone know if `Task.WhenAny(IEnumerable<Task>)` will work as expected if elements are added to the `list` after awaiting? ie:

```
class lunch {

    private List<Task> lunchTasks = new List<Task>();

    public void MakeLunch() {
        Task makeSandwich = new Task();
        Task eatSandwich = new Task();
        makeSandwich.Delay(-1);
        eatSandwich.Delay(-1);
        lunchTasks.Add(makeSandwich);
        lunchTasks.Add(eatSandwich);
        await Task.WhenAny(lunchTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void CleanUp() {
        Task cleanUp = Task.CompletedTask;
        lunchTasks.Add(cleanUp);
    }
}
```

Assuming `CleanUp()` is called after `MakeLunch()` asyncronously, will `MakeLunch()` ever return/complete?

Comment: Why you no try?

Comment: @John Because that code will not compile ;o)

Comment: You have bigger problems, this is not thread safe, it wouldn't compile anyway, i am guessing your next step would be an async void which would most likely be the wrong approach.. anyway the answer to the question is no, you wouldn't expect it to await new tasks (even if you could do it in a thread safe way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Both [`WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) and [`WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) methods are making immediately a defensive copy of the supplied enumerable, as you can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs.html#f16158c687359df9):

```
public static Task<Task> WhenAny(IEnumerable<Task> tasks)
{
    if (tasks == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("tasks");
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    // Make a defensive copy, as the user may manipulate the tasks collection
    // after we return but before the WhenAny asynchronously completes.
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    foreach (Task task in tasks)
    {
        if (task == null) throw new ArgumentException(Environment
            .GetResourceString("Task_MultiTaskContinuation_NullTask"), "tasks");
        taskList.Add(task);
    }

    if (taskList.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment
            .GetResourceString("Task_MultiTaskContinuation_EmptyTaskList"), "tasks");
    }

    // Previously implemented CommonCWAnyLogic() can handle the rest
    return TaskFactory.CommonCWAnyLogic(taskList);
}
```

So any later modifications to the enumerable will be ignored.